# css html undesirable div wrapping

Tags: html, css

I've already tried so many things I'm about to go crazy.

How do I keep cgroup from wrapping when the browser's zoom is magnified or if the right side of the browser is dragged to the left to minimize the browser's window width?

When the div wraps cpanel's top-left corner re-anchors from the fpanel's top-right to fpanel's bottom-right.

Not that it matters, the end product has a large grid in cgroup.  When the page is opened sometimes, depending on how the browser is sized on screen, cpanel wraps to the bottom of the page, out of sight, because cpanel is actually below the bottom of the browser's window.  So users thing the grid doesn't exist.

Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="min-width: 1730px; min-height: 1050px; max-width: 1735px; max-height: 1055px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:red; overflow: hidden;">
        <div id="mpanel" style="min-width: 1730px; max-width: 1730px; min-height: 35px; max-height: 35px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:lightgray; background-color:slategray;">
        </div>
        <div id="fpanel" style="float:left; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; min-height: 990px; max-height: 990px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:lightgray; background-color:lightblue">
            fpanel
        </div>
        <div id="cpanel" style="float:right; min-width: 1430px; max-width: 1430px; min-height: 990px; max-height: 990px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:lightgray; overflow: auto;">
            <div data-container="cgroup">
                cgroup-cpanel
            </div>
        </div>
        <br style="clear: left;" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak `#fpanel`s `width` to `296px` (or whatever value benefits you):

```
<div id="fpanel" style="float:left; min-width: 296px; max-width: 296px;">
```

Snippet below:

```html
<div style="min-width: 1730px; min-height: 1050px; max-width: 1735px; max-height: 1055px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:red; overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="mpanel" style="min-width: 1730px; max-width: 1730px; min-height: 35px; max-height: 35px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:lightgray; background-color:slategray;">
  </div>
  <div id="fpanel" style="float:left; min-width: 296px; max-width: 296px; min-height: 990px; max-height: 990px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:lightgray; background-color:lightblue">
    fpanel
  </div>
  <div id="cpanel" style="float:right; min-width: 1430px; max-width: 1430px; min-height: 990px; max-height: 990px; border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:lightgray; overflow: auto;">
    <div data-container="cgroup">
      cgroup-cpanel
    </div>
  </div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I swear I worked on that.  But it looks & works great now.